# How automatically define navigational properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Let these 2 classes,

A Parent class

```
class Parent{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> child { get; set; }
 }
```

And a Child class

```
class Child {

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int Parent_Id { get; set; }

    public Parent Parent{ get; set; }
}
```

I would like to set a new child class like this:

```
var child = new Child();
MyParentInstacnce.child.Add(child)
```

However, when I set the parent class state.

```
db.Entry(child).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
db.Entry(MyParentInstacnce).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

I got the fallowing error:

> Additional information: A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'Parent_Id' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'Parent.Id' on the other end.

This problem is solved setting mannualy the value of `child.Parent_Id` to the current parent id.

I would like to know if is somehow possible to the EntityFramework set automatically the relational properties by doing `MyParentInstacnce.child.Add(child)`

How can I configure Entity Framework to automaticaly define navigational properties?

OBS

Entify Frameworks is able to make this happens., All you need to do is to DO NOT create the navigational properties. Then the navigational will be under the hood and the EF will make all the work. However in this case I really need to be able to read the navigational properties.

Comment: automatically?! you mean magically? try `fluent api`

Comment: Yes, "magically" is quite exagerated. Entify Frameworks is able to make this happens., All you need to do is to DO NOT create the navigational properties. Then the navigational will be under the hood and the EF will make all the work. However in this case I really need to be able to read the navigational properties.

Comment: What version of EF is this? I can't repro it with EF6. By the way, referring to asp.net is irrelevant.